# Name Shadowing in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Recently, I face this warning in my IntelliJ Idea. But I don't have any solution for that...
Also, I don't want to use the `@Suppress("NAME_SHADOWING")`.
I'll be grateful if you guide me.
This is my code:

```
fun add(
    @Parameter id: Long?
): someClass {
    myTable?.content?.firstOrNull { it.add }?.id?.let { id ->
        db.products.readById(id)?.let { db.products.delete(it) }
    }
    return remove(id)
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Name shadowing means that you are using variables with the same name in different scopes, making it more likely that you by accident refer to the wrong one. The solution is to rename them to be different. In your case it's the variable `id`. It is both the parameter of the function and it is also defined after the first `let`. So you could for example do this to remove the warning:

```
fun add(
    @Parameter id: Long?
): someClass {
    myTable?.content?.firstOrNull { it.add }?.id?.let { id2 ->
        db.products.readById(id2)?.let { db.products.delete(it) }
    }
    return remove(id)
}
```

Comment: `id2` seems not indicative, since is inside the `let` then `safeId` indicates that is not null.

Comment: @cutiko Thank you, adding the `safe` prefix seems like a good approach. By the way, it should be noted that it's not exactly `let` that makes it not null, but rather `?.`.

Answer (score 2):

```kotlin
fun add(
    @Parameter id: Long?
): someClass {
    myTable?.content?.firstOrNull { it.add }?.id
        ?.let { id ->
            // Here you have two variables named "id" (the other being the function parameter)
            db.products.readById(id)?.let { db.products.delete(it) }
        }
    return remove(id)
}
```

Simply rename one of the parameters and the warning will go away.